# Linux copy range of folders

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I found this link with an example of how i can actually copy range of files https://serverfault.com/questions/370403/copy-a-range-of-files-in-command-line-zsh-bash, using this

```
$cp P10802[75-83].JPG ~/Images/.
```

Is there any way i can also copy range of folders or directory ?

Maybe something like this `$cp -r folder[001-999] ~/images./`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close - you would use curly braces:

```
$ cp -r dir{001..999} ~/images
```

edit - actually, I just tried it your way, looks like that would work, too. Experimentation is a great way to learn things in unix/linux!

Answer (score -1):

it's define Linux copy range of folders:-

```
$ shopt -s extglob  # to enable extglob
$ cp !(b*) new_dir/
```